# Character Controller. Jumping Does not work Correctly. Lands In Air

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can Anyone Tell me what's wrong with this script. Whenever I try to get my character to jump, the animation is delayed for a second. When I land, he lands above the ground and then drops down. It looks like the character controller is hitting the ground first, so he hovers above the ground before actually dropping onto it.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class JumpingState : State
{
    bool grounded;

    float gravityValue;
    float jumpHeight;
    float playerSpeed;

    Vector3 airVelocity;

    public JumpingState(Character _character, StateMachine _stateMachine) : base(_character, _stateMachine)
    {
        character = _character;
        stateMachine = _stateMachine;
    }

    public override void Enter()
    {
        base.Enter();

        grounded = false;
        gravityValue = character.gravityValue;
        jumpHeight = character.jumpHeight;
        playerSpeed = character.playerSpeed;
        gravityVelocity.y = 0;

        character.animator.SetFloat("speed", 0);
        character.animator.SetTrigger("jump");
        Jump();
    }

    public override void HandleInput()
    {
        base.HandleInput();

        input = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }

    public override void LogicUpdate()
    {
        base.LogicUpdate();

        if (grounded)
        {
            stateMachine.ChangeState(character.landing);
        }
    }

    public override void PhysicsUpdate()
    {
        base.PhysicsUpdate();


        if (!grounded) // if not in landing state
        {
            velocity = character.playerVelocity;
            airVelocity = new Vector3(input.x, 0, input.y);

            // velocity = velocity.x * character.cameraTransform.right.normalized + velocity.z * character.cameraTransform.forward.normalized;
            velocity.y = 0f;
            // airVelocity = airVelocity.x * character.cameraTransform.right.normalized + airVelocity.z * character.cameraTransform.forward.normalized;
            airVelocity.y = 0f;
            character.controller.Move(gravityVelocity * Time.deltaTime +
                                      (airVelocity * character.airControl + velocity * (1 - character.airControl)) *
                                      playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        gravityVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        grounded = character.controller.isGrounded;
    }


    void Jump()
    {
        gravityVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: It turns out, that it was the animation itself. I was not expecting that.